# Upgrading WebSockets to TLS

Tags: http, redirect, ssl, websocket, http-status-code-301

For HTTP, it is possible to upgrade all requests to HTTPS with a 301 response.

For websocket, however, it doesn't seem to be that easy. If I redirect the  ws://127.0.0.1 request to wss:/127.0.0.1, I get an "error: undefined" in the browser using the test on websocket.org (and yes, certificate is trusted and works for wss if used directly). The initial request is made, and the redirect sent out. However, there is no second request on the TLS port.

The specification only covers redirects briefly.

- Is upgrading ws to wss possible?
- Do I need to send WebSocket specific headers even with the redirect response? (Currently, I don't – and the specification lists redirecting before completing the handshake)
- Any other thing that I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For HTTP, it is possible to upgrade all requests to HTTPS with a 301 response.

(Nitpicking) That's not really an upgrade of a request but instead a redirect which results in a different request.

> Is upgrading ws to wss possible?

According to the [websocket standard (RFC 6455)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-18):

> If the status code received from the server is not 101, the
> client handles the response per HTTP [RFC2616] procedures.  In
> particular, the client might perform authentication if it
> receives a 401 status code; **the server might redirect the client
> using a 3xx status code (but clients are not required to follow
> them)**, etc.

So yes, it might be supported be some clients but not by others. For example in Firefox the relevant property `network.websocket.auto-follow-http-redirects` defaults to false, i.e. it does not follow redirects by default.

> Do I need to send WebSocket specific headers even with the redirect response?

These are only relevant for the upgrading of the request to websocket not for redirects. This means the headers should only be sent in the upgrade response (status code 101).

Comment: Hm kay :( And good to know. For clients that honour the redirect => A simple `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\nLocation: wss://host:port/requestTarget?query\r\n\r\n` is the way to go? Is it also okay to forward to https instead of wss, so that the redirecting endpoint does not need to parse the websocket headers? Is there a better solution to perform the redirect that actually works?

Comment: @Etan: what should a websocket client do with a redirect to http(s)? A websocket clients wants to speak websocket and if the peer does not do it (*"...does not need to parse the websocket headers"*) then the websocket upgrade will fail. But your example redirect to wss:// should work if the client supports redirects for websocket.

Comment: Yep, what I assumed. Wondered if there is an exception to allow for generic redirect-to-SSL endpoints that do not care about what they are redirecting to the other port. Will adjust mine to redirect websocket requests to wss:// and also adjust clients to make sure that they always access the wss version directly.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon whether the webSocket client implementation processes 3xx status codes or not.  The [webSocket specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) does not require a client implementation to do so.  Here's a quote from the spec:

> If the status code received from the server is not 101, the
> client handles the response per HTTP [RFC2616] procedures.  In
> particular, the client might perform authentication if it
> receives a 401 status code; the server might redirect the client
> using a 3xx status code (but clients are not required to follow
> them), etc.  Otherwise, proceed as follows.

Comment: Same wording is for regular HTTP 301 responses – however, for those, every major browser actually honours the redirect. It's strange that there is an exception for websockets.